# how to run sql query where coumn_name have comma separated values?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CustomerID  cat_id  ContactName  Address    City    PostalCode  Country
1   Alfreds 13      Maria Anders Obere Str  Berlin  12209   Germany
4   Around  13,14   Thomas Hardy 120 Hanov  London  WA1 1DP UK
```

what is the query to get 14 data ?
I have tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM `customers` 
WHERE cat_id IN (13,14)
```

but failed.

Comment: Do not store foreign keys as csv. Learn about normalization. For the meantime use find_in_set().

Comment: i know it. but i want that solution

Answer (score 2):

Fix your data model!  Why is it wrong?

- Numeric values should be stored in a column with the correct type, and that is not a string.
- These look like ids.  Foreign key relationships should be properly defined.
- SQL has lousy string processing capabilities.
- Queries using string operations generally cannot be optimized, making optimal use of indexes, table statistics, and partitions.
- SQL has this really great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*.

So, you should have a table with one row per `customer_id` and `cat_id`.  This is often called a "junction table" or "association table".

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other peoples really, really, really bad design decisions.  If so, you can do what you want using `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(13, cat_ids) > 0 and  -- or is that "or"
      find_in_set(14, cat_ids) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `customers` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(13, `cat_id`) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET(14, `cat_id`) > 0
```

**Note:** You shouldn't store value like this!

---

Your tables should look like the following instead to avoid a solution using `FIND_IN_SET`:

**table `customers`:**

```
CustomerID | ContactName  | Address   | City   | PostalCode | Country
         1 | Maria Anders | Obere Str | Berlin | 12209      | Germany
         4 | Thomas Hardy | 120 Hanov | London | WA1 1DP    | UK
```

**table `customers_cats`:**

```
customer_id | cat_id
          1 | 13
          4 | 13
          4 | 14
```

**table `cats`:**

```
CatID | Column1
---------------
   13 | abc
   14 | def
```

So the query would look like the following:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM `customers` c LEFT JOIN `customers_cats` cc ON c.CustomerID = cc.customer_id 
WHERE cc.cat_id IN (13, 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work :

```
SELECT * FROM $tbls WHERE CONCAT(',',cat_id,',') LIKE '%,14,%';
```

Though you should consider normalising it.